# Why cannot I use Debug.Assert() with a method accepting dynamic and returning bool?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, conditional-attribute

Here's my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic param = null;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(whatever(param));
    }

    static bool whatever(object param)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I run it I get `RuntimeBinderException` with the following message:

> Cannot dynamically invoke method 'Assert' because it has a Conditional attribute

Yes, `Assert()` has `ConditionalAttribute` on it. Yet there's exactly one `whatever()` method that returns `bool` no matter what the method accepts.

What exactly does runtime complain about? Why cannot it use the `bool` and pass it into `Assert()`?

Comment: Try `Assert((bool)whatever(param))`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: it's even more interesting that that works than the more obvious `Assert(whatever((object)param))` (which also works). No doubt the language specification will explain somewhere why the call to `whatever` is dynamically bound even though there is no other method that could possibly be called.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel: I cannot see how this question is a duplicate of that one.

Comment: The linked question is not a duplicate. Although it offers roughly the same workaround, it does not answer the *why*.

Comment: @sharptooth I can't see how that question isn't? you're not passing a bool there. It is typed as `dynamic` which is what compiler is complaining. Even though whatever returns bool, result of a dynamic expression is always dynamic. You need a cast there.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: the question is why it's typed that way. `whatever` cannot return anything other than `bool` regardless of its argument. It would make perfect sense if the type of the expression was `bool`, but apparently any method call involving a `dynamic` parameter has type `dynamic`. It would be nice to have that in an answer somewhere (with references).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: I wouldn't ask this if `whatever()` was declared to return `dynamic` but it is declared to return `bool` and I simply don't see how something returning `bool` magically becomes dynamic.

Comment: As usual, Eric Lippert [has the answer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/10/22/a-method-group-of-one.aspx): static type determination does not take precedence because 1) it's not worth optimizing for and 2) in order to remain compatible with future declarations. This is why the type of `whatever(aDynamic)` is `dynamic` even though `whatever` will "always" return a `bool`.

Answer (score 2):

The actual call in `Main` gets translated into a `CallSite`, because you're invoking the call with a `dynamic param`. The `CallSite` does all the preparation it needs in order to invoke this method at **run-time**. But, the problem is, that `Assert` has a `Conditional` attribute on it, which means it needs to pass information to the compiler pre-processor at **compile-time**

This [blog post explains](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2007/10/15/trivia-about-the-conditional-attribute.aspx):

> Conditional attributes can be placed on methods (and attributes in
>   whidbey) to instruct the compiler to conditionally remove calls to the
>   function if a symbol is not defined. This can be useful for debug-only
>   functionality, like Debug.Assert, which has  a Conditional("DEBUG") on
>   it.
>
> Conditional takes a string argument. **If that string is defined (as
>   determined by the compiler's preprocessor), then the compiler emits
>   the method call. If the symbol is not defined, C# still compiles the
>   method, but does not compile the calls.**

And later, to strengthen our point:

> The Conditional attribute is **entirely handled by the compiler without
>   any cooperation from the runtime.** The method is still jitted normally,
>   but the compiler just doesn't emit the calls if the symbol is not
>   defined.

Now, we have a conflict. We can't pass parameters to the compiler pre-processor at run-time (to tell it if "DEBUG" is defined or not), only at compile-time, but the method will only be invoked at run-time, because that's when we'll infer the type of our `dynamic` value.

That's why the binder yells at run-time that this method can't actually be invoked, because that would be breaking the `ConditionalAttribute`.

### Bonus:

This is what actually gets called:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object param = null;
    if (Program.<Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site1 == null)
    {
        Program.<Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site1 = CallSite<Action<CallSite, Type, object>>.Create(Binder.InvokeMember(CSharpBinderFlags.ResultDiscarded, "Assert", null, typeof(Program), new CSharpArgumentInfo[]
        {
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType | CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.IsStaticType, null),
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null)
        }));
    }
    Action<CallSite, Type, object> arg_CB_0 = Program.<Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site1.Target;
    CallSite arg_CB_1 = Program.<Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site1;
    Type arg_CB_2 = typeof(Debug);
    if (Program.<Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site2 == null)
    {
        Program.<Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site2 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, Type, object, object>>.Create(Binder.InvokeMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None, "whatever", null, typeof(Program), new CSharpArgumentInfo[]
        {
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType | CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.IsStaticType, null),
            CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null)
        }));
    }
    arg_CB_0(arg_CB_1, arg_CB_2, Program.<Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site2.Target(Program.<Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site2, typeof(Program), param));
```

Comment: How did you obtain this code?

Comment: @sharptooth Via [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)